# Rails 5 - Join Polymorphic Search - syntax error, unexpected ',',

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following query:

```
folder.children.joins( "INNER JOIN folders ON items.itemable_id = folders.id" ).where( folders: { "key LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%" } )
```

And I am getting the following error and I'm not sure why:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => here( folders: { "key LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%" } ) ^

 syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end E ?", "%#{params[:search]}%" } ) ^
```

Here is the search query:

```
localhost:3000/api/1/folders/155.json?search=a
```

Comment: What value do you have in `params[:search]`

Comment: I have the letter a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

You just add the whole condition in a single where raw query

```
folder.children
  .joins("INNER JOIN folders ON items.itemable_id = folders.id" )
  .where("folders.key LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

So this will create a query ending with

```
Select * FROM items 
INNER JOIN folders ON items.itemable_id = folders.id 
WHERE folders.key LIKE '%a%';
```

Comment: This is what it does, and it doesn't error, but it also doesn't find anything:

SELECT `items`.* FROM `items` INNER JOIN folders ON items.itemable_id = folders.id WHERE `items`.`ancestry` = '267' AND (folders.key LIKE '\'%Pets%\'')

Comment: Just replace the where condition with `.where("folders.key LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")`

Comment: Add `''` around `?` ?

Comment: No need it adds it automatically. I just checked with rails console

Comment: `User.where("users.email LIKE ?", "%pqrs%")
#=> User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."verified" = 't' AND (users.email LIKE '%pqrs%')`